# Manually add item to flutter Stram builder in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have made flutter streambuilder that creates a flutter listview from results returned from a query.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _usersStream,
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Something went wrong');
                  }

                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Text("Loading");
                  }

                  return ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                      (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        Map<String, dynamic> data =
                            document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        addChildBtn();
                        return ListCard(
                          firstName: data['childFirstName'],
                          lastName: data['childLastName'],
                          points: data['points'],
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

It returns a listCard, a custom widget I made which consists of a container. However, I want to have a container always in the listview, regardless if there any items returned from the steam or not.

Comment: Modify your `ListCard` custom widget to have a `Text`. If this is not the case, your question is pretty unclear

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact question. did you find an intelegent away for that?

my workaround which is not super, I added one document in firestore with specfic name, then in the list view builder I check for the name, if matched I return my fixed customized item, if doesn't match then I return the regular card.
the result is what you want, the constrain is that if you have different categories in your firestore database, then you will need to add this specific document everywhere.